# Why is $E(X^2) - 2E(X)E(X) + E(E(X)^2) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$?

Tags: probability

For a given random variable $X$ and the expected value $E(X)$, my lecture notes claim that

$E(X^2) - 2E(X)E(X) + E(E(X)^2) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$.

Now, it seems like $E(X^2)$ is just transfered to the right side such that

$-2E(X)E(X) + E(E(X)^2) = - E(X)^2$,

but I don't see why. We have

$-2E(X)E(X) = -2E(X)^2$, so I guess that

$E(E(X)^2) = E(X)^2$,

but I don't know how to justify that.

Comment: $E(X^2)$ is a constant, even though $X^2$ is a random variable. The expectation of a constant, there's nothing to expect really.

Comment: $E(X^2) - E(X)^2 = VARIANCE(X)$  that's the part you are keeping though, E(X) = the mean ($\mu$) that you can treat like a constant and simplify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E(X)$ is nonrandom, so is $E(X)^2$. And thus, $E[E(X)^2]=E(X)^2$. I think you'll be less confused if you assign a letter, say, $\mu$ to $E(X)$. Then, $\mu$ is nonrandom and, of course, $E(\mu^2)=\mu^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2+E[X]^2-2XE[X]]=E[X^2]+E[E[X]^2]-2E[XE[X]]]$
$$E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2]+E[\mu ^2]-2\mu E[X]$$
$$E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2]+E[\mu ^2]-2\mu^2$$
$E[\mu]=0$,Expectation of a constant is $0$.Hence $E[\mu^2]=0$,
where $E[X]=\mu$.
Hence the answer will be $$E[(X-E[X])^2]=E[X^2]-2\mu^2$$